# Opencart load more products

Tags: php, mysql, opencart

I customize opencart category page and I did a custom pagination, how can I do to click a button with load more and to show products from first page and after products of 1st page to show products of the 2nd page? Only when you select page 2,3, etc to see new page with 2nd or 3rd page products.

Comment: Question is way too broad for SO community. Nevertheless, look for "Browse more" / "Show more" or Infinite Scroll based solutions. It will involve javascript as well. You may also combine lazy loading.

Answer (score 0):

I did it, for anyoane who want to do "load more items" is neccesary to put all items in page and if you want to have only 20 items use a for, put your class of item, when iterator exceeds 20 put display:none in hidden class of item and create a script for load more like this:

```
 function GetMore() {
  var gmarr = document.getElementsByClassName('cat-box hidden');

  for (var i=0; i<52; i++){
      gmarr[0].className='cat-box';
  }
}
```

My classes:

```
.cat-box {
  text-align: center;
}

.hidden {
  display: none;
}
```

Comment: What happens if a category has 1000 products?

Comment: @DigitCart I tried and no problem, the page is loading in ~3 sec